# Flutter text widget breaks up words in the middle to the next line how to stop

Tags: flutter, dart, text, format, longtext

Found the solution, it is to use triple quotes.

Text("""Loooong text ... goes here.""")

This is what did in my project to keep the words from being broken up in the middle of the line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dU4D.png)

Without it. some of these words were broken in half to the new line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NfLe.png)

Answer (score 1):

The below code may help. The key is to use non-breaking zero-width characters "\u200d". For more options, please refer to [this site](https://www.ptiglobal.com/2018/04/26/the-beauty-of-unicode-zero-width-characters/)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right:30),
            child:RichText(
              text: TextSpan(children: [
            TextSpan(
                text: "这是一趟十分令人",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 30.0)),
            TextSpan(
              text: "愉\u200d悦",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
            TextSpan(
                text: "的旅程",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 30.0)),
          ])),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Text(text.replaceAll("\u200b", "")),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?